# java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, webpage-screenshot

I can not take the screenshot. I am trying to save it in project path with folder name Screenshot

I have tried to change the path but still get the same error

```
public void getScreenShot() throws Exception {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\abidk\\Desktop\\chromedriver.exe");    
        WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
        // store the webelement
        WebElement element_node = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@id='hplogo']"));
        // pass the stored webelement to javascript executor
        JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        jse.executeScript("arguments[0].style.border='2px solid red'", element_node);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
         SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("E yyyy.MM.dd 'at' hh:mm:ss a zzz");
            Date date = new Date();
            File scrFile = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
            FileUtils.copyFile(scrFile, new File("./Screenshot/" + "Google" +  "-" +dateFormatter.format(date)+".png"));

    }
```

I want to save the file in project path and call it ScreenShot

Comment: Please include the compete stacktrace

Comment: might not like colons in a file name.

Comment: @JeremyKahan Correct. Windows definitely [does not allow colons in file names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/FileIO/naming-a-file).

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is with the colon ":"

Windows doesn't allow files to be saved with : in file name.

Use `dateFormatter.format(date).toString().replace(":", "-")`

Example:

```
TakesScreenshot screenShotObj = ((TakesScreenshot) driver);
File sourceFile = screenShotObj.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
Instant instant = Instant.now();
String toSavein="D:\\Screenshots";
String fileName = "ScreenShot" + instant.toString().replace(":", "-") + ".png";
File destinationFile = new File(toSavein, fileName);
FileUtils.copyFile(sourceFile, destinationFile);
```

Result:
ScreenShot2020-01-18T11-20-58.238372400Z.png

Note: `Instant instant = Instant.now();` is allowed only above Java 8